# Calculation of Information(Fisher) of a function of Bernoulli random variables.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference, fisher-information

If $ X_1,X_2, ...X_n $ follows iid $ Bernoulli(p) $ then What will be the Fisher's Information $ I_U(p) $ where $ U = X_1 + X_2 + 2X_3 $?

I am facing a problem to find the probability mass function(pmf) of $U$, to be more specific, I don't know what to do with the term $ 2X_3 $ of $U$ where $X_i$s are iid $Bernoulli(p)$. That's why I can not proceed for further calculation.

To calculate the Fisher's Information, I need the pmf as a function of $p$, so that I can take the derivative for $p$.

Kindly help me to find the pmf of $U$.

Comment: Please don't delete and repost questions when you don't get an immediate response https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3858550/fishers-information-of-a-function-of-bernoulli-random-variables

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are the possible values of $U$? Note that $X_1,X_2,X_3$ all take values in $\{0,1\}$, so 
$U=X_1+X_2+2X_3$ can take values $0,1,2,3,4$.

- $U=0\implies X_1=X_2=X_3=0$ and the probability of this happening is $(1-p)(1-p)(1-p)=(1-p)^3$ since $X_i$-s are independent and $P(X_i=0)=1-p$
- $U=1 \implies X_1=1, X_2=X_3=0$ which has probability $p(1-p)^2$ 
   or $X_1=X_3=0, X_2=1$ which also has probability $p(1-p)^2$, 
  so $U=1$ with probability $2p(1-p)^2$
- $U=2\implies X_1=X_2=1,X_3=0$ which has probability $p^2(1-p)$ 
   or $X_1=X_2=0, X_3=1$ which has probability $(1-p)^2p$ 
   so $U=2$ with probability $p^2(1-p)+(1-p)^2p=p(1-p)(p+1-p)=p(1-p)$
- $U=3\implies X_1=X_3=1,X_2=0$ which has probability $p^2(1-p)$ 
  or $X_2=X_3=1,X_1=0$ which has probability $p^2(1-p)$ 
  so $U=3$ with probability $2p^2(1-p)$
- $U=4 \implies X_1=X_2=X_3=1$ which has probability $p^3$.

So $U=\left\{ \begin{array}{ll} 0 & \text{ with probability } (1-p)^3\\
1 & \text{ with probability } 2p(1-p)^2\\
2 & \text{ with probability } p(1-p)\\
3 & \text{ with probability } 2p^2(1-p)\\
4 & \text{ with probability } p^3 \end{array}\right\}$

$\implies \log(f(U;p)) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \log((1-p)^3) & \text{ if } U=0\\
\log(2p(1-p)^2) & \text{ if }U=1\\
\log(p(1-p)) & \text{ if }U=2\\
\log(2p^2(1-p)) & \text{ if }U=3\\
\log(p^3) & \text{ if } U=4 \end{array}\right\}$

$\implies \log(f(U;p)) = \left\{ \begin{array}{ll} \log((1-p)^3) & \text{ with probability } (1-p)^3\\
\log(2p(1-p)^2) & \text{ with probability } 2p(1-p)^2\\
\log(p(1-p)) & \text{ with probability } p(1-p)\\
\log(2p^2(1-p)) & \text{ with probability } 2p^2(1-p)\\
\log(p^3) & \text{ with probability } p^3\end{array}\right\}$

Then, the Fisher's information you need will be $$E\left[-\dfrac{d^2}{dp^2}\log(f(U;p))\right]= -\sum_{i=0}^4 \left(\dfrac{d^2}{dp^2} \log(f(i;p))\times P(U=i) \right)$$

Comment: @Nabil Fawkes4494d3 gave you $f(u;p)$ for each value of $u$; take the log and differentiate w.r.t. $p$. For example when $u=0$ you need to take the derivative of $\log((1-p)^3)$. Thus $\frac{d}{dp} \log f(U;p)$ is a new random variable that has a similar PMF as $U$, but instead of values $0,1,2,3,4$, it has values $\frac{d}{dp} \log f(0;p), \ldots, \frac{d}{dp} \log f(4;p)$. Take the expectation of this random variable.

Comment: @Nabil isn't the mass function $f(U;p)$ evident the last line describing the probabilities of different values of $U$? Refer to angryavian's comment. :)

Comment: @Nabil Fisher's information is the [expectation of the random variable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expected_value#Finite_case) $\dfrac{d}{dp} \log (f(U;p))$, not the individual values, and the expectation is a single number.

Comment: @Nabil see the edit. Do you know how to find the expectation of a random variable? I provided the link in the last comment. You should know how to find the expectation before you go on Fisher's information.

Comment: @Nabil do you understand now?

Comment: The new random variable is $\dfrac{d}{dp}\log (f(U;p))$ and not $\dfrac{d}{dp} f(U;p)$.
 and 
$\dfrac{d}{dp}\log (f(U;p))=\dfrac{d}{dp}\log (f(0;p))$ when $U=0$ (with probability $1$), so clearly the random variable $\dfrac{d}{dp}\log (f(U;p))$ takes value $\dfrac{d}{dp}\log (f(0;p))$ with the same probability that $U$ takes the value $0$, so the probability you want is precisely $P(U=0)$. Please read the comments carefully. I had even edited the answer to include the calculation for the Fisher's information before I posted the last comment.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 Thank you so much. Now, I got it. I have not seen the edited answer. That's why I was confused.

Comment: @angryavian Thanks to both of you.

Comment: @Fawkes4494d3 one more query. Is the right part of the last equation okay or there should be a $ \frac{d^2}{dp^2}$ before the $ log f(i;p)$?

Comment: @Nabil thanks for that. edited.